# "Трудолюбивый" vs "старательный" - есть ли разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Поиск по корпусу русского языка пока не дал значительных успехов, но языковая интуиция подсказывает, что ***старательный*** человек, скорее всего, делает с усердием **то, что предусматривает его социальная роль** — к примеру, старательный ученик пытается досконально выполнить предусмотренное учебной программой задание, старательный работник чётко придерживается рабочего плана и т. д.

Прилагательное ***трудолюбивый***, как кажется мне, лишено этого компонента значения, трудолюбивый человек скорее любит работать в целом, нежели пытается чётко выполнить все пункты некоторой программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**О трудолюбии и старательности**

**Начнем с примеров**. Двухлетний ребенок хочет всё делать сам, да не все может – вот и льются горькие слезы: «Не получается!». **Он любит труд?** Это вряд ли, он просто хочет быть не хуже взрослых. Трехлетнее дитя приходит из сада с новыми знаниями и уже поучает родителей: «Надо стараться!» **Это старательный ребенок?** Скорее целеустремленный, а цель осталась прежней: «я  тоже всему научусь».

А как только научится, то трудиться и стараться становится уже не так интересно. Но мир взрослых рядом, и дети видят другую сторону  старания и труда: если хочешь жить хорошо, надо всё-таки стараться.  Поэтому семилетняя девочка хочет быть отличницей, она учит два языка, весь день занимается уроками. Способности у нее средние, а старания много. Трудно сказать, **любит ли она труд**.

А что там у взрослых, как они относятся к труду? **Любить труд можно по-разному.** Кто-то не любит сидеть без дела,  обязательно надо что-то мастерить, чтобы руки были заняты.  **Трудолюбивые и старательные** сотрудники нужны там, где  всегда есть **много работы**.

Труд бывает **творческий,**  гениальные люди тоже могут быть фанатиками труда. А может быть, они и должны быть фанатиками труда, иначе мир не узнает об их гениальности. Но старательными их не назовешь, они скорее упорные в достижении цели.  **А они-то любят труд?**  Не думаю, труд для них не любовь, а   способ существования и претворения в жизнь своих идей.

Поэтому делаем такой **вывод.**

**Трудолюбие** – это не любовь к труду, разве вы можете сказать: «Как я люблю труд! Я очень, очень его люблю!»

**Трудолюбием** мы называем способность человека выполнять  **большой объем работы**  или быть занятым **постоянной работой** – не все к этому способны. Также трудолюбием может считать **привычку** быть постоянно занятым.

**Старательность** – тоже способность, а также желание выполнить поставленную задачу наилучшим образом. Это качество связано  с устремленностью к результату: научиться полезному делу, хорошо выполнить поручение,  заслужить уважение окружающих,  а также заодно угодить начальству, получить хорошую должность, улучшить свою жизнь и т.д.

**А что там с этимологией?** У этих слов разные и.-е. основы –  ter и ster.  Ключевым понятием **для труда** можно назвать  слово «тереть», а заодно «притеснять, давить, досаждать».  О какой любви здесь может идти  речь хотя бы в историческом плане!

А вот **для старания** однокоренным словом является **стремление**, а также твердость и даже жесткость. Вот такие они на самом деле, эти старательные люди, которые кажутся нам иногда просто скромными. Они тоже целеустремленные, но к целям конкретным и не всегда проявленным.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

Талантливый и **исключительно трудолюбивый** архитектор  Шехтель проектировал и строил во многих городах России.

В середине XX века в одном из графств Англии служил метеоролог, **старательный и пунктуальный.**

А тут он ― **старательный исполнитель** чужих художественных задумок.

Явился **старательный порученец** Валентин Сергеевич.

На пороге ― молодой, **старательный**, румяный от **исполнительности** офицерик.

Это был **молчаливый и очень старательный** парень, но Леонид относился к нему настороженно.

Он и там был **работящий и старательный**.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, эти качества (они могут принадлежать одному и тому же человеку, но совсем не обязательно) проявляются *в разных* ситуациях: *трудолюбивый* человек получает удовольствие от **процесса** работы, а *старательный* - от **результата** той работы, за которую берётся или даже той, которую *вынужден* делать, отложив своё любимое занятие. У первого есть потребность *посвящать своё время* работе, у второго - выполнить начатую работу *наилучшим образом*.