# Любят ли труд трудолюбивые люди?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

**Трудолюбивых  людей у нас любят,** как их не любить! На работе  они особенно хороши.  Поэтому трудолюбие воспитывают   с детства: «Если мальчик любит труд, он хороший мальчик».

**1. А сами-то трудолюбивые  люди любят труд?**

Я думаю, что нет. Любят они только **результаты труда**, это совершенно очевидно. Любовь к труду – она только **кажущаяся**, потому что  всегда любят что-то другое,  **сопутствующее**,  а вовсе не сам труд.

Человек вообще способен любить только то, что ему **приятно, интересно, вызывает положительные эмоции,** причем у каждого своя тема. Особую группу составляют люди деятельные – они  не то чтобы трудолюбивые, но просто получают удовольствие от жизни, только находясь в динамике, в каком-то процессе.

Трудолюбие – это хорошее качество для людей **со средними способностями.**  Если к нему еще добавить немного честолюбия, то человек может добиться хороших результатов в жизни. **Вот именно эти результаты** и любят трудолюбивые.

**2. Любить труд могут только творческие люди**

Возьмем, к примеру, Пушкина, уж он-то точно получал удовольствие от своей работы: «Давно завидная мечтается мне доля, Давно, усталый раб, замыслил я побег В обитель дальнюю **трудов и чистых нег**».  А вот Онегин не имел достаточно любви: «Хотел писать — но **труд упорный Ему был тошен**; ничего
Не вышло из пера его».  Это и понятно: ведь творчество – это не только озарение, но и непростой путь к такому моменту, когда "минута — и стихи свободно потекут".

**3. А любят ли труд дети?**

Вот моя юная знакомая хватает игрушечное ведерко и бежит поливать только что посаженные липы в парке: «Как я люблю ухаживать за природой!».  Родители умиляются: «Трудолюбивая!»  Но любовь – это чувство непостоянное,  и через пару недель ей уже нравится что-то другое. Нет, маленькие дети в какой-либо деятельности могут любить только **новизну, яркие впечатления и новые открытия**. Или тоже **результаты** – например, успешность среди сверстников.

**4. Как воспитать трудолюбие в школьниках**

Способ  только один – сделать учебу **творческим процессом.** Дети  должны **получать удовольствие** от поиска знания,  здесь нужен элемент противоречия, как это случается в процессе настоящих научных открытий.  Но организовать это сложно, вот им и приходится поглощать скучные готовые «истины». **Тяжелый труд, как его любить!**  А в результате мы имеем людей, не умеющих мыслить, настроенных на существующие и единственно правильные решения.

**Вопрос дискуссионный**, продолжение темы [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461754/Трудолюбивый-vs-старательный-есть-ли-разница](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461754/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-vs-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Цитата: "Трудолюбивый человек получает удовольствие от процесса работы, а старательный – от результата той работы, за которую берётся".

Comment: Чтение затрудняет и сбивает с мысли   о б и л и е   выделенных слов, фраз, заголовков. Разве смысл текста без выделенных мест труднодоступен?

Comment: Спасибо, учту, буду работать над формой.  Вероятно, надо в каждом абзаце выделять тему и ключевое слово. Меня же обычно затрудняет сплошной тест, где структура никак не обозначена, логика изложения не всегда понятна, а уж о выделении ключевых слов и говорить не приходится. Но ничего, всем нравится.

Comment: Так и полагал, что именно в этом есть чаяние всего народа, он, как известно, без обозначения ключевого слова в каждом предложении логики не узрит.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это уже дело  вкуса. Я люблю читать текст по диагонали, то есть быстро его  просматривать, Мне так удобно, возможно, это удобно и другим. Но всё-таки неясно ваше пристальное внимание к оформлению моих ответов:  неужели  все остальные очень хороши, и только мои вас не устраивают? А впрочем, можно попробовать писать иначе - с одними пробелами между словами. Что не сделаешь, чтобы вам угодить!

Comment: Не насилуйте себя. Достаточно, что к «неоформленным» комментариям спокойно относитесь.

Comment: В в чем вопрос? Вопрос  лингвистический?  Или вас интересует: в чем разница между трудом и старательностью? Если да, то вы и сами прекрасно ответили на этот вопрос.

Comment: Трудолюбивый человек для меня — тот, кто много трудится работает. Трудолюбивый человек для меня прежде всего ассоциируется с физическим трудом. И не обязательно, чтоб любил работать. Главное — способность физическая.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, любят, причем охотно берутся за любую полезную работу и не могут сидеть без дела.
2. Творческие люди **ненавидят** рутинный труд и любят заниматься только тем, что им интересно. Со стороны могут выглядеть "лентяями". Творческий труд часто связан с поиском, и о возможности положительного его *результата* (в науке или изобретательстве) бывает даже заранее неизвестно - есть *надежда на результат*, которая держится на интуиции.

Comment: Alex_ander, я про этот тип людей уже говорила, это деятельные люди. У них организм так настроен, что без движения они ощущают дискомфорт, вероятно, даже на физическом уровне.  (Я, к примеру, не могу долго стоять и чего-то ждать, просто заболеваю от этого.) А физическая или какая-то другая нагрузка может сопровождаться выделением эндорфина – гормона удовольствия.  Это именно тот симптом, который вы описали –  берутся за любую полезную работу и не могут сидеть без дела.

Comment: Это не любовь к самому труду, если считать, что труд – это вклад человека в общественный продукт, то есть та работа, которой вы занимаетесь как специалист, получивший образование по своему профилю; и не та работа, которая обеспечивает ваш материальный достаток. А что касается творческих людей, ненавидящих рутинный труд, то они хотя бы свой творческий труд любят. Результат их тоже интересует, но это такой результат, который нужен не только им самим,  но и обществу в целом.